# How do I update my list View when my button is clicked, in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been trying to do this the whole day but have not been able to figure it out. When I did figure it out with the help of intents, it only creates one object of the task but after that just keeps updating that same one.

```
package com.learning.taskapp;

import static com.learning.taskapp.MainActivity2.active;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    List<task> taskList;
    Button button;
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> addTaskLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        String taskName = data.getStringExtra("taskName");
                        boolean taskStatus = data.getBooleanExtra("taskStatus", false);
                        if (taskName != null) {
                            taskList.add(new task(taskName, taskStatus));
                        }


                    }
                }
            });

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        taskList.add(new task("Making the fucking breakfast",false));
        taskList.add(new task("Walk the dogs",false));
        taskAdapter adapter = new taskAdapter(getApplicationContext(), taskList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        button = findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                goToSecondActivity();
            }
        });

    }
    private void goToSecondActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        addTaskLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
}
```

This was my mainActivity code.

```
package com.learning.taskapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    Button Confirm;
    static public boolean active;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Confirm = findViewById(R.id.button);
        Confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String taskName = editText.getText().toString();
                goToMainActivity(taskName);
            }
        });
    }

    public void goToMainActivity(String taskName){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("taskName", taskName);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

This was my Second Activity.
Kindly Help me.

I tried doing it with the help of the intent

```
Intent getIntent = getIntent(); 
        String taskName = getIntent.getStringExtra("taskName"); 
        taskList.add(new task(taskName, false));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And as I said above, what happens is One object is created but it refuses to make more. Kindly help me with this.